# Java IO File Prefix string too short - but its not

Tags: java, file

Trying to create simple .tar.gz file from one directory. There is my code:

```
File destinationFile = new File("/var/www/swOfflineFeeds/Companies/2/")
File sourceFile = new File("/var/www/swOfflineFeeds/Companies/2/64cacf30-b294-49f4-b166-032a808d73cd/")
println("destinationFile exists: " + destinationFile.exists()) //prints true
println("sourceFile exists: " + sourceFile.exists()) //prints true

Archiver arch = ArchiverFactory.createArchiver(ArchiveFormat.TAR, CompressionType.GZIP)
File archiveFile = arch.create("64cacf30-b294-49f4-b166-032a808d73cd", destinationFile, sourceFile)
```

And I am getting error message:

```
| Error 2018-02-15 12:47:08,925 [http-bio-8183-exec-1] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - IllegalArgumentException occurred when processing request: [GET] /socialwall/test/index
Prefix string too short. Stacktrace follows:
Message: Prefix string too short
    Line | Method
->> 1978 | createTempFile in java.io.File
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|     51 | create         in org.rauschig.jarchivelib.ArchiverCompressorDecorator
|     19 | index . . . .  in com.manas.socialwall.TestController$$EQjisHuy
|    198 | doFilter       in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter . . . in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|   1145 | runWorker      in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run            in java.lang.Thread
```

As you can see filename is correct. I googled and some people mention bug in Java IO File class. Is this true ? How to avoid this problem?

Comment: And? What is wrong with your code? Provide a [mcve] please. EDIT: can you add the complete stacktrace ?

Comment: I am sorry, I added error message. Hope it's clear now.

Comment: I notice, but with the complete stack trace, we could see where a temp file is created.

Comment: Added full stacktrace

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Checking the [library code](https://github.com/thrau/jarchivelib/blob/master/src/main/java/org/rauschig/jarchivelib/ArchiverCompressorDecorator.java) used we see that the create method look like :

```
public File create(String archive, File destination, File... sources) throws IOException {
     ...
     File temp = File.createTempFile(destination.getName(), archiver.getFilenameExtension(), destination);
```

The prefix is the first parameter. If you check what [`File.getName()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getName%28%29) do :

> Returns the name of the file or directory denoted by this abstract pathname. This is just the last name in the pathname's name sequence. If the pathname's name sequence is empty, then the empty string is returned.

In your case.

```
File destinationFile = new File("/var/www/swOfflineFeeds/Companies/2/");
System.out.println(destinationFile.getName());
```

> 2

The prefix received is too short for the temp file to create, it expect a prefixe of at least 3 character. See [`File.createTempFile`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

> prefix - The prefix string to be used in generating the file's name; must be at least three characters long

In your case, it seems you just provide a folder, provide the file name instead (with at least 3 character).

---

[An issue has been created](https://github.com/thrau/jarchivelib/issues/64) by Michael.

Comment: This is so stupid, but thank you very much for answer! I edited name to "company_2" and everything works

Comment: @Teemo, it should have been documented more in the API used, the requirement of `File` were not documented on the `create` method. PS : Don't forget to check what to do when [someone answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @Michael thanks for that. Add in the question and have provide my input on the issues. It should be quite easy to resolve.