# Can't upgrade to gradle 6.6 because of "prefix string too short"

Tags: gradle

I'm trying to upgrade an existing project from gradle 6.5.1 to 6.6.

But when I build, it fails with an error:

```
Successfully started process 'Gradle build daemon'
An attempt to start the daemon took 1.116 secs.
The client will now receive all logging from the daemon (pid: 122). The daemon log file: /home/****/.gradle/daemon/6.6/daemon-122.out.log
Starting build in new daemon [memory: 519.0 MB]
Using 1 worker leases.
Starting Build
Compiling initialization script '/home/****/agent/workspace/Enrich_build_PR-41@tmp/artifactory/init-artifactory449129576487257952gradle' using SubsetScriptTransformer.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Failed to create Jar file /home/****/.gradle/caches/jars-8/8535adf040d7c5fdb7fd6bc28bb0ef3f/ok.
> Prefix string too short
```

Running with --debug, the only thing that looks relevant is:

```
020-10-05T16:38:54.631+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.component.model.LoggingAttributeMatchingExplanationBuilder] Selected match ok from candidates [ok] for {org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.jvm.version=8, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}
```

Which seems like an internal gradle issue. How can I fix or avoid this error?
(I also tried 6.6.1 and have the same problem)

It happens when I run "./gradlew help" as well, so it shouldn't be related to my build config.

The stacktrace looks like:

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.GradleException: Failed to create Jar file /home/****/.gradle/caches/jars-8/8535adf040d7c5fdb7fd6bc28bb0ef3f/ok.
    at org.gradle.internal.classpath.ClasspathBuilder.jar(ClasspathBuilder.java:47)
    at org.gradle.internal.classpath.InstrumentingClasspathFileTransformer.transform(InstrumentingClasspathFileTransformer.java:76)
    at org.gradle.internal.classpath.InstrumentingClasspathFileTransformer.transform(InstrumentingClasspathFileTransformer.java:70)
    at org.gradle.internal.classpath.DefaultCachedClasspathTransformer$TransformFile.lambda$schedule$0(DefaultCachedClasspathTransformer.java:261)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Prefix string too short
    at org.gradle.internal.classpath.ClasspathBuilder.buildJar(ClasspathBuilder.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.classpath.ClasspathBuilder.jar(ClasspathBuilder.java:45)
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: Try running gradle with `--stacktrace` to see the full exception stacktrace

Comment: Looks like you are also using an initialization script. What is it doing?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue seems to be related to artifactory plugin

Check https://github.com/jfrog/jenkins-artifactory-plugin/issues/349

Answer (score 0):

## Quick Fix

Recommend to **downgrade to Gradle 6.5** to resolve the issue.

### Further Details / Possible Cause

While I don't know the root cause of why this happens, I get the same 'Prefix string too short' error, in Gradle 6.6.1.
And in particular, this is my exact error message, from a Mac:

```
Failed to create Jar file /Users/****/.gradle/caches/jars-8/8535adf040d7c5fdb7fd6bc28bb0ef3f/ok.
```

Since the 'prefix' error came from Java, I looked at my Java install thinking that might be the problem.  In my case Java was many versions behind, so I upgraded to 8u261 however that didn't seem to change anything.

For how it starts in our case:

- User kicks off Jenkins job for Gradle
- Jenkins job fails specifically for being unable to create the file in the cache directory.  And the number actually is the same each time for the cache too; it's always '**.gradle/caches/jars-8/8535adf040d7c5fdb7fd6bc28bb0ef3f/ok**' and not a different number.  So it's almost like that is statically set from somewhere.

So focusing on that error, I came across this similar-ish prefix error, for a Java issue.  While this doesn't fully answer the issue we see, it does help explain why it could be a 'legitimate' error as it thinks the file name is less than 3 characters.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48806741/14403001

- So it *feels* like it's interpreting the end of that string as being the file name.  Namely it might think that **ok** at the end of the path is actually a filename, and being less than 3 characters it sends the 'Prefix string too short' error.  Keep in mind this is speculation and I don't know if this is actually the cause or not.

We happened to have another Mac that was running Gradle 6.5 that was working fine with the exact same Jenkins job.  So we downgraded from Gradle 6.6.1 to 6.5 to match the other and are back working like before.
Since we used Mac, Brew didn't actually have an older version to roll back to.  So I was forced to uninstall gradle via brew, then follow the steps below to install and point to an older version of Gradle.
Hoping it's easier for you via yum/apt to downgrade than it was for myself.
https://gradle.org/install/#manually